# Nexus 7 blank screen

Tags: nexus-7, screen

After watching a bit of 4oD last night on my Nexus 7, I turned it off. When I tried to start it up this morning, I was greeted with a blank screen whilst being plugged into the charger. I held down the power button, and Google flashed onto the screen for about 3 secs. When I disconnected from the charger, the screen switched off completely.

I have only had this for a week and a half. It is obviously still under warranty. Can I just send it back? I am completely dumb when it comes to computer issues!

Comment: Just plugged it into my laptop, I now have a black screen with some coloured 'crackling' moving across the screen. I haven't dropped it or got it wet!

Comment: To me, it sounds like flat battery. Charge the device as it is for couple of hours with its original charger and cable and try powering on with a very long press on that power button.

Comment: Its been charging all day, tried the power button hold down, nothing happened. JUst held down volume down and power button now have the green android with his chest open,the only option on the screen is fastboot mode. started this and got a blank green screen. I shut it down and again pressed the volume down and power button, have again the green android??? STUCK!!

Comment: Ok, if you would like to learn things, I would suggest you to learn and do unlock the boot loader, flash a factory image to restore. On the other hand if you don't want all these fuss, better return it.

Comment: Thank you Narayanan, I have come down this morning managed to power it up, it is obviousley a problem with the charging. It seems to be a common fault. will return I think!

Answer (score 0):

The same thing had happened to my N7. Here's what worked for me.

Let your device stay in that state for as long as the battery lasts, i.e wait till the battery is dead.

After that is done, Power on the devise by Holding the two volume buttons and then connect the charger or connect to a computer.

Use your volume buttons to navigate to `START` and click on the power button

That should bring it back to life

`Edit` Here is a photo of the boot loader I found on Google which shows the `Start`

[image]